# How could I compare polygons with appropriate circle?

Tags: arcmap, geometry

My problem is that I have a polygon shapefile with 1034 records which are the Greek municipalities. My goal is to compare the shape of every record with the circle. In other words, I want to observe the deviation of the polygons from the perfect shape-circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to ArcMap 10, then [Bounding Containers](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=3D230972-1422-2418-34A5-2F3FFF97C238)
has an option create minimum area bounding circles around features.  That would get you started to at least compare the actual area to that of a circle bounding its extent.

Answer (score 5):

Standard methods of comparing polygons to circles exploit some of the defining characteristics of circles.  One is that of all plane figures of a given area, the circle has the smallest perimeter.  To compare an area (measured in square units) to a perimeter (measured in linear units), we deduce the circle's diameter *d* from its area, *A*:

```
d = 2 Sqrt(A/pi).
```

Its perimeter is

```
L = d * pi.
```

Both *d* and *L* are in linear units.  We therefore compare 2*Sqrt(A/pi) to L/pi where *A* is the area of an arbitrary polygon and *L* is the length of its perimeter.  The ratio is

```
r = L/pi / (2*Sqrt(A/pi)) = L/Sqrt(A) / (2*Sqrt(pi)) = 0.282095 * L/Sqrt(A).
```

By construction, this ratio is always 1 or greater and equals 1 if and only if the polygon is a circle.  Therefore you can interpret (r - 1) as a measure of deviation from a perfect circular shape.

As an example, consider a square of side *s*.  Its area is *A* = *s*^2 and its perimeter is *L* = 4 *s*.  We find

```
r = 0.282095 * 4s / Sqrt(s^2) = 0.282095 * 4 = 1.12838.
```

This is 0.12838 greater than 1.  Note how this measure is independent of the size (*s*), position, or orientation of the polygon: it depends solely on its *shape.*

This idea is closely related to that of the [tortuosity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tortuosity) of a curve.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness I have managed to find my code for calculating shape metrics of polygons and moved it to https://code.google.com/p/shape-metrics/.

It provides implementations of Blair & Bliss, Lee & Salle, Ritter, Boyce & Clark, Miller, Gibbs and Zusne's methods.  See http://www.citeulike.org/user/ianturton/article/6901886 for fuller details of the methods.

Comment: +1 Good reference.  The full article is available at http://www.geovista.psu.edu/publications/MacEachren/MacEachren_GA-B_85.pdf. (Beware: the descriptions of the area:perimeter metrics are incorrect.) The most striking element of the article is its characterization of "compactness" as the mean distance between all pairs of points within the shape (relative to a given probability distribution of those points).  This is a 4D integral which can be done efficiently (for uniform distributions) via a triangulation of the shape.  BTW, a disk of area *A* has "compactness" of 0.51083 * Sqrt(A).