# Explanation of the Thinness ratio formula?

Tags: geometry, validation, slivers

I am looking for sliver polygons and am using the following formula to identify which polygons have a smaller area-to-circumference ratio (aka Thinness Ratio):

```
4 * pi * area/(length*length)
```

That much I understand. But what is not fully clear, is the 4 * Pi bit and why the length has to be squared. Can someone explain this in simple terms?

Comment: I believe that should be perimeter * perimeter rather than length * length. For a circle, the value is 1. When you think about it in terms of area/squared perimeter it starts to make sense. Compare a square that is 5x5 to a rectangle that is 9x1, both having a perimeter of 20, but the square having an area nearly 3 times bigger than the thinner rectangle. You can derive a similar result with calculus.

Comment: Length is the circumference of the Polygon - so the same as perimeter

Comment: Perimeter would be the preferred terminology in mathematics, I would think. The point, anyway, is that an area reaches its maximum when a shape is regular, and falls rapidly as the sides become less equal in length, assuming a constant perimeter.

Comment: If you consider the roles 2 and *pi* play in area and perimeter calculations, it shouldn't be difficult so see how two squared and a single *pi* could be used to normalize the ratio of area to circumference (hint: substitute for *r*)

Comment: You ask the same question in [StackExchange Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336265/explanation-of-the-thinness-ratio-formular) and the comment give you an explanation. This ratio is also known as Circularity ratio

Comment: @ Vince- What role does 2 play?

Comment: Cross-posting on SE sites is discouraged.  Please review the SE meta document on the subject: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068. The best way to resolve the issue would be to choose which site you would like to keep your question and delete the other one.

Comment: OK. I thought that by cross posting this particular question in 2 forums I could get 2 different view points. In that case, I would like to keep it in gis.stackexchange because the question comes from this direction.

Comment: This question is also answered at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10905/how-could-i-compare-polygons-with-appropriate-circle/10925#10925

Answer (score 2):

The **Thinness Ratio** describes the relation between a polygons perimeter to its area using geometric attributes of a circle as a basis for comparison. A definition can be found in  [*Microscope Image Processing, page 201*](https://books.google.com/books?id=uGWmR0f_350C&pg=PA202&lpg=PA202&dq=thinness%20ratio&source=bl&ots=SkvDogwtS6&sig=ACfU3U1HyCJmgy4uT7mt_1hIxPSj5Sg78Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi7-f7a48znAhUqlnIEHZrJBHYQ6AEwEnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=thinness%20ratio&f=false). For a circle, we know that

```
A = pi * r^2
```

and

```
p = 2 * pi * r
```

Solving the perimeter equation for `r` gives:

```
r = p / (2 * pi)
```

which can then be substituted into the area equation to give:

```
A = pi * (p / (2 * pi))^2 = pi * p^2 / (4 * pi^2)
  = p^2 / (4 * pi)
```

Collecting all terms on one side, we then get:

```
A * 4 * pi / (p^2) = 1
```

which is a true statement for circles. We then *define* the Thinness Ratio (`TR`) to be:

```
TR(A,p) = A * 4 * pi / (p^2)
```

When the polygon in question is a circle, we know that `TR = 1`. Otherwise, `TR` gives us a measure of how "squashed" or *non-circular* the polygon in question is. In fact, the book I referenced earlier defines a polygon's *Circularity* as the reciprocal of the Thinness Ratio and these concepts are linked. In practice, we use the Thinness Ratio because we can readily compute a polygon's perimeter and area.

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind the **thinness ratio** is that once known the perimeter of the unknown shape if the shape is similar to a circle the measured area should be equal to the theoretical area of a circle with the circumference equal to the perimeter of the unknown shape.

Knowing that the area of the circle is `pi*r**2` and that the perimeter `p` is `2*pi*r` hence `r =  p /2*pi` substituting `r` in the formula of the area we obtain that the theoretical area of the circle with perimeter `p` is `(p*p)/4*pi`. Hence the ratio of the measured area vs theoretical is: `(4*pi*Ames)/(p*p)`.